# Sorting a generic list of two types

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, collectors

```
  List.add(new TheDList("abc123", 9986));
  List.add(new TheDList("ads314", 9986));
  List.add(new TheDList("dal192", 3214));
  List.add(new TheDList("sam273", 3214));
  List.add(new TheDList("wor213", 7643));
  List.add(new TheDList("wos987", 1292));
  List.add(new TheDList("cat202", 9986));
  List.add(new TheDList("jga213", 1292));
  List.add(new TheDList("gog113", 1493));
  List.add(new TheDList("aba231", 9831));
```

There's a Class called TheDList and it has the name and value
as `final` variables, but it also has a constructor and (get) methods.

The list above is from a method called sort and the elements in the list above are shuffled before the list is sent to me through this method.

there are two methods within the Class TheDList, `getValue` and `getString`
how do I sort this using `Collector` or sort methods within Java?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yepp, I've edited now. Sorry @user7

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`reversed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed()) method of `Comparator` to sort *descending* and employ the [`thenComparing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing(java.util.function.Function)) method to break ties.

Using Comparator methods, it’s a one-liner:

```
public void sort(List<TheDList> list) {
    list.sort(
      comparing(TheDList::getValue)
      .reversed()
      .thenComparing(TheDList::getString));
}
```

---

To leave the original list unchanged and instead return a new, sorted list, use [`ArrayList`’s copy constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Collection)) before sorting:

```
public List<TheDList> sort(List<TheDList> list) {
    list = new ArrayList(list);
    list.sort(
      comparing(TheDList::getValue)
      .reversed()
      .thenComparing(TheDList::getString));
    return list;
}
```

Comment: you compare by value and make it desc by reversing the values in the list and later you compare again by Strings and it's automatically asc becuase that's the default? Thanks alot!

Comment: how would you do if u had to create a new list with the sorted version of the list? @bohemian

Comment: @Qazzablanca see edits to answer for a non mutating version.